# Steam always starts in Big Picture mode

Tags: steam

I don't know why but for a few days Steam has been always starting in Big Picture mode.

It has even been doing this for the login screen:

[image: Big Picture login screen]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked if the option to always start in Big Picture Mode is set? It's on the Interface tab.

Comment: Three things : 1) How did that box ticked it by itself >< because I'm sure I never ticked that ? 2) I'm blind and missed that in the parameters 3) Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

Click *Steam* > *Settings* then the *Interface* tab and uncheck *Start Steam in Big Picture Mode*.

[image: Interface section of the Settings window]